# Recording Audio with Adobe Flex on Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, apache-flex, mobile, adobe

is it possible to record Audio on iOS and Android with Adobe Flex Mobile? I can't find anything about that feature on Adobe's website.

Thanks,
Pat

Answer (score 0):

I post you two pointers (for Flash): I never personally tried to use this with Flex/AIR (iOS and Android) but maybe you could give it a try.

http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/create-a-useful-audio-recorder-app-in-actionscript-3/

http://code.google.com/p/micrecorder/downloads/list